# How to reference a data range that keeps changing?

Tags: google-sheets, graph, charts, reference, absolute

I have a report in my google sheets that updates automatically every 4 hours and adds new records to it, meaning that there are always new rows being added to it.
In another overview sheet, I have a graph that refers to the data from the report. I have marked the data range as: 'REPORT'!A1:N119
But the reality is there will be new data added after cell N119, so I want to always include these automatically. How do I reference the data range? Do I absolute the cells?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We don't know what your spreadsheet looks like, what data it contains, data types, what "the report" looks like or what it does or how it is formed. But in general, using full-column references is a good place to start, e.g., `REPORT!A:N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `'REPORT'!A1:N119` use an open range: `'REPORT'!A1:N`

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense.However, google sheets does not allow me to do that when selecting a data range for the graph. When I put in 'REPORT'!A1:N it automatically changes it to 'REPORT'A1:N1000

Comment: @A.Be by adding rows 1000+ it should auto-expand. if not you can add rows at the bottom first and then set it for your graph